# GWT - What's a good GUI editor for GWT in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea

The one that ships with IDEA is nothing more than a GWT project creation tool.  Is there a better plugin?  Is there a standalone GUI editor for GWT?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question directly, there is no such thing as a Intellij IDEA GUI WYSIWYG editor for GWT for the moment.

The most popular/feature complete WYSIWYG editor for GWT is [Instantiations GWT Designer](http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/). It is available only for Eclipse though.

The GWT team also provide a [list of tools and libraries.](http://code.google.com/intl/nn/webtoolkit/tools.html). It seem rather incomplete though as it does not list Ext-GWT and GWT-Ext libraries (the most popular widget libraries).

Be warned however that most WYSIWYG editor only support the basic widgets of GWT. If you have custom widget, you may not be able to use them in the editor.

---

[Edit] As of August 2010, Instanciation has been acquired Google

Answer (score 1):

I've never used these personally but a few things I've found include:

- http://www.gdevelop.com/ (extension to JDeveloper so it might not be appropriate for you if you're using IDEA and not wanting to download and use JDeveloper for your GWT project)
- http://code.google.com/p/gwt-html-editor/

Comment: The HTML editor is a widget that is used to edit HTML in GWT. It is not a GWT Editor

Answer (score 1):

You have here a pretty comprehensive [list of GWT plugins/editors](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/component/content/article/36-core-java/66-gwt-plugins-for-various-ides.html). Those are geared towards GWT projects creation, and not so much towards GUI.

However, you also have [**VistaFei**](http://www.wirelexsoft.com/VistaFei.html) (not very active at the moment, but worth checking out). It comes with its own eclipse distribution:

[alt text http://blogs.zdnet.com/images/burnette_vistafei_control_grid_398.png](http://blogs.zdnet.com/images/burnette_vistafei_control_grid_398.png)

> A visual Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for building AJAX apps based on Google Web Toolkit (GWT)  for all AJAX-enabled platforms. Applications are built by "drag & drop" from a Palette on the basis of What You See Is What You Get.
>
> VistaFei is a visual feature-full Java development environment geared towards apps development based on GWT. Applications are developed in Java then compiled and debugged using GWT Compiler and Debugger, and launched to a browser all from within same environment.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically looking for an IDEA plugin, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't one yet. We're going to have to wait until 2016 when Google takes over the world; everything will be so much easier then! ;)