# Is there GWT UI designer for IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea

This question [had already been asked here on StackOverflow in late 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357886/gwt-whats-a-good-gui-editor-for-gwt-in-intellij-idea). However, since then GWT improved rapidly and so did IntelliJ IDEA. And what's more important, count of IDEA plugins increased. So besides [GWT Designer for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gwt-designer-gui-builder) , is there something similar for IntelliJ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no GUI Designer for GWT in IntelliJ Idea yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT designer is only for eclipse. not for netbeans or intellij. you know there are some for [intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html)  and [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html) that supports development of GWT but there is not any plugin  like gwt ui designer for them.

Comment: Shame, let's see what they'll do about this later.